# GtkPaned move-handle signal from mouse?

Tags: c, gtk

Reading through a GTK+ tutorial and I wanted to print out a message any time the pane handle was moved, and print it's position along with that. So...

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(hpaned), "move-handle", G_CALLBACK(resized), GTK_PANED(hpaned));

...

void resized(GtkPaned *paned)
{
    g_message("Something like %d!", gtk_paned_get_position(paned));
}
```

Except that only prints out the location when I press a scroll button (arrows, page keys, etc). That makes plenty of sense based on the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkPaned.html#GtkPaned-move-handle)... but, what about getting a signal from a click-and-drag event? Surely that's a more common way to resize a pane than moving it with the arrow keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation points out, `move-handle` is a [keybinding signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/gtk3-Bindings.html#keybinding-signals), which is not what you want here. To observe all moves of the handle, connect instead to the notification signal of the `position` property:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(hpaned), "notify::position",
                 G_CALLBACK(resized), GTK_PANED(hpaned));
```

Comment: Lovely. That was cool. How would one go about only receiving one notification from a move? As in, the user drags it back and forth, but the only signal caught is the "dropped" signal. Or is a per-pixel thing just the way this kind of reporting is?

Comment: Since the paned continuously updates its position, it wouldn't make much sense to give a single notification. To implement a single point when the move is "finished", you can manually listen to the button-up event.